# How to make my htaccess file rewrite all traffic to cgi-bin

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make my htaccess file redirect all traffic except that to /images, /css, and /javascripts to the cgi-bin.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^css/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^javascript/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cgi-bin/.*$
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/$1 [L]
```

I want a request for: **example.com/index** to retrieve **example.com/cgi-bin/index**

but I also want a request for: **example.com/images/foo.png** to retrieve **example.com/images/foo.png**

What is wrong with my file?  I keep getting this error: **Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the leading `/` in all of your `RewriteConds`, which are required, though they should not be used for `RewriteRule` in .htaccess, which does cause confusion.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/$1 [L]
```

You also don't need the `.*$` so I removed them to make it more efficient.